# WebSocket connection to '...' failed: Invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I use express and socket.io

My node server is running on 127.0.0.1:3000
and i have connected it

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {query: 'id=' + user.id});
```

There is a warning in my browser console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?id=ecad7e1a009eb4f943ead0b4db8d62c4&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=0RMaRoZb7U67td_2AAAD' failed: Invalid frame header
```

Also it runs well. There is no problem :). But i wondered.

Comment: do you recieve any warnings on the server side?

Comment: No, there is no errors or warnings on my node server

Comment: Same issue here. I get the error message but everything works fine. Have you found a workaround? - Bests

Comment: I am facing same problem and currently investigating it. Though my problem is only on heroku not on local.

Comment: I couldn't fix this warning. So, i've run my project with this warning and it haven't created any problems for 3 months.

Comment: Does your problem fixed? I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check versions of socket client and server. They should be the same.